# Backbone.js. Не могу найти ошибку в скрипте

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Только начинаю изучение фреймворка и javascript. 
Задача создать приложение одностраничное, с 10 квадратиками. 
Особенность в том, что у каждого должно быть уникальное описание в CSS.

Пытаюсь решить с использованием 10 templat'ов.
Но скрипт не запускается.
Код:

> alert("script entry");

```
$(function () {

blocks = [
            {number: "1", state: "block1" },
            {number: "2", state: "block2" },
            {number: "3", state: "block3" },
            {number: "4", state: "block4" },
            {number: "5", state: "block5" },
            {number: "6", state: "block6" },
            {number: "7", state: "block7" },
            {number: "8", state: "block8" },
            {number: "9", state: "block9" },
            {number: "10", state: "block10" },
];

var BlockModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    defaults:{
        "state": "block1",
        "number": "1"
    }
});
var BlockCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    model: BlockModel,
});
var blockNumbers = new BlockCollection([  
           model:BlockModel
            ]);

var BlockView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "blockTag",
    className: "blockClass",
    templates: { // шаблоны каждого квадратика
        "block1": _.template($('#block1').html()),
        "block2": _.template($('#block2').html()),
        "block3": _.template($('#block3').html()),
        "block4": _.template($('#block4').html()),
        "block5": _.template($('#block5').html()),
        "block6": _.template($('#block6').html()),
        "block7": _.template($('#block7').html()),
        "block8": _.template($('#block8').html()),
        "block9": _.template($('#block9').html()),
        "block10": _.template($('#block10').html())
    },

    render: function () {
        var state= this.model.get("state");  
        var tmpl = this.templates(state); 
        $(this.el).html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));  
        return this;
    }
});

var appView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#block"),

    initialize: function(){
        this.collection = new blockNumbers(blocks);
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){

         _.each(this.collection.models, function (this.model) {
            that.renderBlock(this.model);
        }, this);
    },

     renderBlock: function (inputModel) {
        var blockView = new BlockView({
            model: inputModel
        });
        this.$el.append(blockView.render().el);
    }

});

var app = new appView();
```

});

Индексный файл:

> <div id="block">

```
<script type="text/template" id="block1">
  <div class="block1"><%=number%></div>
 </script>

<script type="text/template" id="block2">
   <div class="block2"><%=number%></div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block3">
  <div class="block3">3</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block4">
  <div class="block4">4</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block5">
  <div class="block5">5</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block6">
  <div class="block6">6</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block7">
  <div class="block7">7</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block8">
  <div class="block8">8</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block9">
  <div class="block9">9</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="block10">
  <div class="block10">10</div>

</script>
```

</div>

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Например `model: item` -> `{model: item}`, но код менее диким не станет.

Comment: На работоспособность не повлияет.
Как не дико?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плохо знаком с Backbone, так что, как-то так: http://jsfiddle.net/3nrwp/